# Entity for table not managed by Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So I'm using Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2 for a new web application but we have a few common tables shared among different applications.

We need to access these tables (read-only, there would be no updates) but I don't want Doctrine to manage them.  My vision is to create an entity for it so Doctrine can use it, including relations to it, but not have it do create/alter table statements when I do doctrine:schema:update.

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your entities (manually or using [generator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)) and mark them as [readOnly](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity)

Comment: This seems to not work for me! I set my entity to @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true) and it still shows me, that it will ALTER the table when I execute: doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql. What am I doing wrong?